# Java Implement Publish Subscribe without using Iteration

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

Most Publish subscribe implementations uses some form of iteration to notify the subscribers either by using a for/while loop to call their listener methods or by placing the new topic of interest on each of them's blocking queue.

I want to implement a publish subscribe that rather "watches" something ie a location, a variable or file or something and then pulls the new topic from its stored location. I want them all to be notified "approximately" at the same time.

This is because the previous solutions are slow because I have a large number of Subscribers and iterating through them takes time.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the issue is blocking the modifying thread, then maybe you run the notifier loop in a background thread.

Comment: Take a look at Akka (or other actors framework).

Comment: The issue is the Iteration, not the blocking. Thanks for suggesting Akka. This is a learning exercise so I would like to implement it without libraries

Comment: I'm not sure you can get better performance with something like this, seeing you could just partition the list and iterate over the subscribers concurrently. As an aside, have you checked out any publish-subscribe frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
public class Producer {
    public static Object publishedObject;
    public static ConcurrentLinkedDeque<Object> previousObjects;
    private int size;

    public publishObject(Object object) {
        previousObjects.offerLast(publishedObject);
        publishedObject = object;
        size++;
        if(size > 50) {
            previousObjects.removeFirst();
        }
    }
}

public class Consumer implements Runnable {
    private Object lastConsumedObject;
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            if(Producer.publishedObject == lastConsumedObject) {
                sleep(500);
            } else {
                Iterator<Object> iterator = Producer.descendingIterator();
                Object next = iterator.next();
                Object newLastConsumedObject = next;
                do {
                    this.process(next);
                } while(iterator.hasNext() && 
                    (next = iterator.next()) != lastConsumedObject);
                lastConsumedObject = newLastConsumedObject;   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that the `Producer` has a "publish location" that the `Consumers` can poll, and it also stores previously published objects in a `LinkedList` in case a `Consumer` fails to notice one.  The Consumer polls the publish location and sleeps if there's been no change, otherwise it processes the published object and iterates through the previously published objects in case it missed a publish event.

The semi-busy waiting might kill your performance here.  An alternative is to have two classes of consumer: `SinkConsumer` and `RelayConsumer`.  You would have one `RelayConsumer` per hardware thread (e.g. 8 `RelayConsumers` if you have four cores and hyperthreading).  The `Publisher` publishes the message to the `RelayConsumers`, who then each publish the message to numberOfSinkConsumers/numberOfRelayConsumers `SinkConsumers`.

Comment: Thanks for this. The second alternative 2-Stage is what I have now but its still quite slow - hence myquest. The problem with  your shared publishedObject is that it will result in lots of cache misses if all Consumers wake up at the same time. If the consumers sleep randomly that may also result in race conditions.... I thought this is a very common problem and there would be a template/solution  of what people have done

Comment: @Farouk Alhassan I don't think you have a race condition so long as the producer adds new objects to the list of previous objects before it updates the published location. Also, if you replace the LinkedList with a ConcurrentLinkedDeque then you won't run into any ConcurrentModificationExceptions

Comment: the second alternative looks like the best I can do. Tx